# Is there a way to use CSS transitions to move an element to the right place so an animation looks good?

Tags: css, css-transitions, css-animations

I'm trying to make a carousel using '[transition-duration](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition-duration)' for the slide change effect with a bunch of slides like:

```
|  slide 1 |  slide 2 |  slide 3 |  slide 4  |  slide 5  |

                 <----           ---->      ( <-- left and right arrow buttons )
```

Pressing the left arrow moves slide 1 "around" to the end so it'll look like this:

```
|  slide 2 |  slide 3 |  slide 4 |  slide 5  |  slide 1  |
```

I was thinking an intuitive way to animate this would be to:

1. animate slide 1 **to the left**, off screen
2. (somehow position slide 1 off screen to the right of slide 5)
3. then animate slide 1 **from the right** so that it's next to slide 5

But, I'm not sure how to do step 2 without javascript:  Is there a CSS transition way? Maybe a CSS animation way using keyframes or something?  thanks!

Comment: I don't think this is possible with CSS (because you'd be re-ordering elements based on the position of, potentially, later-siblings). If you didn't need slide 1 to move to the end (after slide 5) then it *might* be possible to move left/right and display the appropriate image.

Comment: Thinking it through, it does *seem* possible using `@keyframe` animations; however, it would be very lengthy, so I see no advantage in doing it this way. In fact, it strikes me as *so* convoluted that I don't even want to attempt it in a JSFiddle! You would probably be better off with using JS.

Comment: hahaha dre #1 best answer